# Karate UI - Loop with chrome

Tags: karate

I have a ui test where I need to loop in the same chrome window (session).  Essentially, I'm using scenario outline and each run adds an item to a cart.  Right now, it's launching a new chrome window with each loop.  How can I make it reuse the same window?

Eg:

Scenario outline:

- driver.url = [www.site.com/addtocart](http://www.site.com/addtocart)
  Click 1
  Click 
  Click "add to cart"
  Examples:
  Item|
  Orange|
  Pineapple|

Scenario:
Click "submit cart"

Comment: don't use a `Scenario Outline`. use a second feature file in a loop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!